# How do you add an animation to minimize JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the AnimateFX library, which is just a compilation of node animations.

```
AnimationFX fx = new ZoomOut(background);
fx.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //background.setScaleX(1.0D);
        //background.setScaleY(1.0D);
        //background.setScaleZ(1.0D);
        //background.setOpacity(1.0D);

        // -- some wait function --

        Stage stage = (Stage) background.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setIconified(true);
    }
});
fx.play();
```

This block results in the window minimizing, but now the window is both transparent and minuscule.

If I uncomment the background node transformations and comment `stage.setIconified(true)`, the animation ends with the window returning to full size, as expected.

However, if I uncomment the background node transformations without commenting `stage.setIconified(true)`, the program minimizes without running the background node transformations.

I assumed it was some synchronizing issue, but adding a wait function in the `// -- some wait function --` locale simply resulted in the program waiting **without** the background node transformations running, and then minimizing.

A bit confused as to why this happens.

**EDIT**

Here is some runnable code that replicates the problem. I find that if I replace the `ImageView` with a `Button` and change the event to that of a button action, then the problem no longer occurs.

```
package app;

import animatefx.animation.AnimationFX;
import animatefx.animation.ZoomOut;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    VBox background;
    @FXML
    ImageView minimize;

    @FXML
    public void onMinimizeClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        AnimationFX fx = new ZoomOut(background);
        fx.setSpeed(0.75D);
        fx.setResetOnFinished(true);
        Stage stage = (Stage) background.getScene().getWindow();
        fx.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> stage.setIconified(true));
        fx.play();
    }

}
```

**Edit #2**

Here is my main class

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is my sample.fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:id="background" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="app.Controller">
  <AnchorPane fx:id="content" prefHeight="464.0" prefWidth="500.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956&#10;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="minimize" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="175.0" onMouseClicked="#onMinimizeClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
    </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</VBox>
```

Comment: can you provide runnable code so we can regenerate your experienced behaviour

Comment: I've provided it in an edit of the question

Comment: can you provide the fxml file also

Comment: I tired your code and it's doing as expected I don't experience that kind of behaviour you mentioned or I can't regenerate it with your provided code

Comment: I provided the rest of my files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of this behaviour but I managed to solve it by adding an image inside the `ImageView` in the `FXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:id="background" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<AnchorPane fx:id="content" prefHeight="464.0" prefWidth="500.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D4956&#10;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="minimize" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="175.0" onMouseClicked="#onMinimizeClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" >
            <Image url="file:image/iamge.png"/>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
</VBox>
```